# DB2: Converting varchar to money

Tags: db2

I have 2 varchar(64) values that are decimals in this case (say COLUMN1 and COLUMN2, both varchars, both decimal numbers(money)).  I need to create a where clause where I say this:

```
COLUMN1 < COLUMN2
```

I believe I have to convert these 2 varchar columns to a different data types to compare them like that, but I'm not sure how to go about that.  I tried a straight forward CAST:

```
CAST(COLUMN1 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) < CAST(COLUMN2 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
```

But I had to know that would be too easy.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be that easy, why do you think it's not?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Charles, yes, I'm receiving the error "Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function 'DECIMAL'..SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018".  I'm using the exact syntax I gave in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is that easy...this works fine...

```
select cast('10.15' as decimal(9,2)) - 1
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

You've got something besides a valid numerical character in your data..
And it's something besides leading or trailing whitespace...

Try the following...

```
select *
from table 
where translate(column1, '           ','0123456789.')
      <> ' '
     or translate(column2, '           ','0123456789.')
      <> ' '
```

That will show you the rows with alpha characters...

If the above does't return anything, then you've probably got a string with double decimal points or something...
You could use a regex to find those.

Comment: Charles, this makes sense.  I discovered when I run the query for the previous full month, it runs fine with no errors.  When I run it for the current month, I get the "invalid character" error.  That to me says that there is a result in the current month that has a non-numeric character kicking back the error.   Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just FYI, it was NULLs causing the issue.  I got rid of those and the query ran fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a UDF like this to check which values can't be cast to `DECIMAL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DECIMAL(i VARCHAR(64)) RETURNS INTEGER
    CONTAINS SQL
    --ALLOW PARALLEL -- can use this on Db2 11.5 or above
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE NOT_VALID CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22018';
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT_VALID RETURN 0;

  RETURN CASE WHEN CAST(i AS DECIMAL(31,8)) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END;
END
```

For example

```
CREATE TABLE S ( C VARCHAR(32) );
INSERT INTO S VALUES ( '  123.45 '),('-00.12'),('£546'),('12,456.88');
SELECT C FROM S WHERE IS_DECIMAL(c) = 0;
```

would return

```
C        
---------
£546     
12,456.88
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in ability to do this without UDFs.
The `xmlcast` function below does "safe" casting between `(var)char` and `decfloat` (you may use `as double` or as `decimal(X, Y)` instead, if you want). It returns `NULL` if it's impossible to cast.
You may use such an expression twice in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
  S
, xmlcast(xmlquery('if ($v castable as xs:decimal) then xs:decimal($v) else ()' passing S as "v") as decfloat) D 
FROM (VALUES ( '  123.45 '),('-00.12'),('£546'),('12,456.88')) T (S);

|S        |D                                         |
|---------|------------------------------------------|
|  123.45 |123.45                                    |
|-00.12   |-0.12                                     |
|£546     |                                          |
|12,456.88|                                          |
```

Comment: Yes, handy if you don't have permissions to create a UDF.