# db2 sql query - joins between char and decimal

Tags: sql, join, casting, db2

Im trying to do a Left outer join sql query for 2 DB2 tables -through aqt editor. Join  to happen between char and decimal fields.

For the where clause im providing ,the char and decimal fields always hold only 19 digits - no characters or decimals.

Tried cast function to convert char to decimal so join can happen b/w 2 decimal fields, also tried to cast both char and decimal to  integer . Been getting errors like:

1. cursor is not in a prepared state,arithmetic overflow
2. other arithmetic exception occured.

It is quite a big query- Here is the line where the error occurs-

```
left outer join aTable on cast(aTable.charField AS Decimal(19,0)) = bTable.decimalField
```

bTable.decimalField is Decimal type with Length 19

aTable.charField is Char type with Length 30.

Comment: Please show us the queries that raise the errors.

Comment: @GMB edited the post to add the line in the query where the error occurs.

Comment: sounds like some of your data can't be cast to a DECIMAL. Depending on your Db2 version, you could use a function like this to show all the values that can't be so cast https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904676/9525344

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to cast a DECIMAL into a CHAR, but not always possible to cast a CHAR into a DECIMAL. I would suggest you try the first option instead of the second one (that you are using). Unless, of course, you are sure the data is in perfect, pristine condition.

For example you could rephrase your join as:

```
left outer join aTable on aTable.charField = '' || bTable.decimalField
```

The example above uses the most simple *rendering* from a numeric to a char value. Ultimately the exact rendering should take into account aspects such as:

- Leading zeroes,
- Possible negative sign of the numeric value,
- Other formatting quirks such as dashes, commas, or dots.

You'll need to tweak the rendering accordingly.

A final note: the conversion strategy (left to right, or right to left) greatly affects the optimization options of the engine. If you make the change you may end up with a faster or slower query. In any case, you'll end up with a correct solution.